# ChromeOS errors in GCP Logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I'm seeing errors in StackDriver logging for my Compute instance. The logs are showing repeated issues every hour, creating a lot of noise. I have a Spring Boot API deployed in a container to a VM in Compute Engine using latest stable version of Container OS.

I'm relatively new to GCP and don't understand what is causing this issue, searches have come up empty so far.

```
Failed to call method: org.chromium.SessionManagerInterface.RetrieveActiveSessions: object_path= /org/chromium/SessionManager: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.chromium.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

```
CallMethodAndBlockWithTimeout(...): Domain=dbus, Code=org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown, Message=The name org.chromium.SessionManager was not provided by any .service file
```

```
Error calling D-Bus proxy call to interface '/org/chromium/SessionManager': The name org.chromium.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

The same 3 lines are repeating every hour. Anyone aware of what might be causing this or how to fix/suppress these?

Comment: Can you provide more context to your environment. When you say latest version of container OS, are you referring to Google Container Optimized image or other Distros like, CoreOS? Also, is this error affecting your Application, and could you also provide more information on what you mean by "a lot of noise"?

Comment: I'm not sure what more context you need in regard to the environment. I have a VM running and its sole purpose is serving a Spring Boot API. It is deployed as a docker container to Google Container Optimized image. These errors do not seem to be effecting anything, but I'm trying to figure out why they are showing up/what is causing them and how to prevent them from continuing to show in logs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I looked into this error, and as per my findings:

- The error message that you have been receiving is a manifestation of Chrome to reliably exit shortly after starting up.
- The UI’s job (which encompasses *Chrome*, the *session_manager* and the *window manager*) gets shut down by upstart because of it's *thrashing*, and when the test tries to restart the *session_manager*, the *session_manager* cannot communicate it over to the D-Bus.

The crash collection software in Container OS was originally for Chromebooks (The laptop using Chrome browser). So the code typically expects Chrome and some other related software on the system.

However, Container OS is a server OS, and does not have Chrome. So if Chrome is missing, the software will report some errors. They are actually **not real failures**, just some verbose error messages.

Overall, It is **safe** to ignore these logs and continue using your VM Instances.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Much appreciated. I suspected it was of no consequence, but was hoping there might be a remedy for it. Unfortunately it sounds likes this is a Google problem that I'm not going to solve myself.

Comment: Our compute engine is logging this and is 'overutilized' when we are running a server doing NOTHING.  we suspect this thrashing to be using up CPU.  Is there a way to fix this so it never starts at all?